# adminLTE 2 + fullcalendar assets conflicts

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, fullcalendar, adminlte

i'm trying to integrate this two libraries but without success, as you can see on the following pics:

[first only the adminLTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wOOH.png)

[Now adminLTE + fullcallendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEc1g.png)

You can see wen i try to acess te both libraries at the same time the browser lose format

Bellow follow my codes:

Layout view(adminLTE):

```
<head>

  <link href=' <?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-ui.min.css"); ?>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"); ?>"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"); ?>'></script>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Superar CRM</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
  page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
  apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dist/css/skins/skin-green.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function(){
      $('#inner-content-div').slimScroll({
          height: '600px'
      });
    });

</script>


</head>


<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->

<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"); ?>"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/dist/js/app.min.js"); ?>"></script>

<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
     Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
     user experience. Slimscroll is required when using the
     fixed layout. -->

<!-- SLIMSCROLL -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url('assets/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js'); ?>'></script>

<!-- EXCEL -->
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url('assets/excel/excellentexport.min.js'); ?>'></script>

<!-- DATAPICKER -->
<link href=' <?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css'); ?>' rel='stylesheet' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js'); ?>'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url('assets/plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.js'); ?>'>
</script>

<!--calendar-->
```

Fullcalendar view:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Full Calendar CRUD</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />

        <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

        <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js'></script>
        <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js'></script>
        <script src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/main.js'></script>

        <style>

            body {
                margin: 40px 10px;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .fc th {
                padding: 10px 0px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                background:#F2F2F2;
            }
            .fc-day-grid-event>.fc-content {
                padding: 4px;
            }
            #calendar {
                max-width: 900px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .error {
                color: #ac2925;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
            .event-tooltip {
                width:150px;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
                color:#FFF;
                padding:10px;
                position:absolute;
                z-index:10001;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-size: 11px;

            }
            .modal-header
            {
                background-color: #3A87AD;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                        <div id='calendar'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="error"></div>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" id="crud-form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="time">Time</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4 input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
                                    <input id="time" name="time" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="color">Color</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="color" name="color" type="text" class="form-control input-md" readonly="readonly" />
                                    <span class="help-block">Click to pick a color</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean "without success"?

Comment: Please ask your question clearly here.

Comment: Without success means is not working the way I want

Comment: check your console and check the error message

Comment: how are these two samples of code related such that they somehow conflict? They can't both be part of the same page, because they both have `<html>` tags to indicate the start of a new document. Can you be clearer about exactly what is happening and what your problem is? Explain what you are actually doing and report any errors you are getting.